# Lua 5.1 # operator and string comparisons (performance)

Tags: performance, lua, comparison

For this:

```
b = #{1,2,3}
c = 'deadbeef' == 'deadbabe'
```

Does b gets computed in O(n) or O(1)? In what scenario? Is the behavior consistent, or context-dependent like sparse arrays behavior?
Is string comparison O(1) or O(n)? I know strings are immutable, and Lua compares hash values but what if 2 different strings hash to the same value?
Please, don't answer with "Don't worry about low-level behavior, son". I am interested in low-level behavior. Thank you.

EDIT

3) Is the result of # stored somewhere, or is it calculated each time I call it for the same array?

Comment: If the low level stuff is important for you, then probably you should use a language where you have control over the low level stuff. You can also look up in the [source](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/), how these things are implemented. But my advice would be: "Don't worry about low-level behavior, son", if you want to code in a dynamically typed, extremely simplistic scripting language.

Comment: The resultant value from using the default # on a table that doesn't have a sequence is undefined (unless 0 applies). Use of arrays for tables is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The length of tables is computed in `O(log n)`. The algorithm is roughly as follows:

- Try to find some integer index mapped to `nil` by taking a step. The step size doubles each time. (If you find a `nil` value at the end of the array part, you can skip this part.)
- When such an index is found, use a divide and conquer algorithm on the interval between this index and the last known non-`nil` index to find an non-`nil` value directly followed by a `nil` value.

See the details [here](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/ltable.c.html#luaH_getn). This algorithm works well if you have a contiguous sequence of values, but can produce unexpected results if the array has holes in between.

EDIT: The results of the builtin `#` operator are not cached, so the above algorithm runs every time you use `#` on a table (without `__len` metamethod).

Regarding string comparisons (for equality): 
Newer Lua versions have two types of strings internally: short strings (usually up to 40 bytes) and long strings. Long strings are compared using `memcmp` (if the lengths match), so you get `O(n)`. Short strings on the other hand are "interned" meaning that when you create a certain short string in Lua, it is checked whether a string with the same contents already exists. If so the old string object is reused, and no new string is allocated. This means that you can simply compare memory addresses to check for equality of short strings, which is `O(1)`.

Comment: Unexpected results is putting it lightly,  `{1, 2, 3, 4, [6]=6}` has a different "length" then `{1, 2, 3, [4]=4, [6]=6}` in 5.2.3

Comment: @rpattiso This is effect is clarified in the Lua 5.2 docs: "Unless a __len metamethod is given, the length of a table t is only defined if the table is a sequence." In other words, don't do that!

Answer (score 4):

Lua strings are stored in a table to avoid creating duplicates of the same strings, so every time a string is created it needs to be hashed and compared to anything with the same hash value as part of it's creation.

The comparison of string objects after creation is O(1) as Lua already ensured they reference a unique string so Lua just compares the underlying pointers.

> *as all string are internalized, string equality becomes
>    pointer equality*
>
> `#define eqstr(a,b)      ((a) == (b))` [lstring.h](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lstring.h.html)

```
x = "deadbeef" -- put in string table
y = "deadbabe" -- put in string table
c = x == y    -- compared pointers
```

For the table case you presented:

From the implentation of [ltabl.c:int luaH_getn (Table *t)](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/ltable.c.html) :

```
t = {1, 2, 3} -- requires creating a table, hashing all the values etc.
b = #t    -- constant time as array part is full and no hash part (ergo # is the array size)
t = [3] = nil
b = #t   -- boundary inside array part, binary search in array,  b=2
b = #t   -- another binary search
t = {1, 2, 3, [1000]=4} 
b = #t   -- array is full, and 4 is not a key in the hash, b = 3
```